# nancy selfhost, with dryioc and bootstrapper -> Method not found exception

Tags: nancy, topshelf, dryioc

At work we require a small application, and decided to test some things we are not really familiar with for this project as well.

I started with a console app, using topshelf to host nancy via the nancy selfhosting package. 
All of this works.

Now I wanted to wire in the DryIoc container into the nancy bootstrapper and got the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'DryIoc.Rules DryIoc.Rules.With(DryIoc.FactoryMethodSelector, DryIoc.ParameterSelector, DryIoc.PropertiesAndFieldsSelector, Boolean)'.
  Source=Nancy.Bootstrappers.DryIoc
  StackTrace:
   at Nancy.Bootstrappers.DryIoc.DryIocNancyBootstrapper.<GetApplicationContainer>b__0(Rules rules)
   at DryIoc.Container..ctor(Func`2 configure, IScopeContext scopeContext)
   at Nancy.Bootstrappers.DryIoc.DryIocNancyBootstrapper.GetApplicationContainer()
   at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.Initialise()
   at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor(INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper, HostConfiguration configuration, Uri[] baseUris)
   at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost..ctor(Uri baseUri, INancyBootstrapper bootstrapper, HostConfiguration configuration)
   at Segrey.Licensing.Web.WebService.Start() in I:\git projects\Segrey.Licensing\Segrey.Licensing.Web\WebService.cs:line 21
   at Segrey.Licensing.Service.Program.<>c.<CreateHost>b__1_2(WebService ls) in I:\git projects\Segrey.Licensing\Segrey.Licensing.Service\Program.cs:line 26
   at Topshelf.ServiceConfiguratorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<WhenStarted>b__0(T service, HostControl control)
   at Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1.DelegateServiceHandle.Start(HostControl hostControl)
   at Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost.Run()
```

My bootstrapper: empty, no registrations yet as I first wanted to test this out
before making it more complex

```
public class Bootstrapper : DryIocNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(IContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        //No registrations should be performed in here, however you may
        //resolve things that are needed during application startup.
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        //Perform registation that should have an application lifetime
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(IContainer container, NancyContext context)
    {
        //Perform registrations that should have a request lifetime
        base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
    }

    protected override void RequestStartup(IContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        // No registrations should be performed in here, however you may
        // resolve things that are needed during request startup.
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
    }
}
```

And in my .Start method for the service via topshelf where the bootstrapper gets assigned

```
public void Start()
{
    var hostConfig = new HostConfiguration() { UrlReservations = new 
    UrlReservations { CreateAutomatically = true } };
    var uri = new Uri(_hostUrl);
    _nancyHost = new NancyHost(uri, new Bootstrapper(), hostConfig);
    _nancyHost.Start();
}
```

Error occurs on new NancyHost(uri, new Bootstrapper(), hostConfig); as soon as I add new Bootstrapper() into the arguments

Comment: Sounds like a versioning issue.  Check your .config file for binding redirects for dryioc.  DryIocNancyBootstrapper thinks it's using version X of dryioc, but instead it's using version Y (due to a binding redirect), which doesn't have that method (either it was removed or it's an older version that doesn't yet have it). Figure out what version DryIocNancyBootstrapper wants and reference that version.

Comment: Because the Nancy.Bootstrapper.DryIoc required DryIoc.dll (>=2.7.0) I had installed the latest dryIoc package. But indeed. I did try a downgrade before to 2.10 (from 2.12). But now that you mentioned this, I actually downgraded to 2.7 and it works. 

Wouldn't have thought of downgrading even further, such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much.

If you could provide this as an answer I will mark this as a solution.

Comment: Naughty DryIoc removing methods in later versions. Binding redirects are all the more common nowadays, so breaking changes like this are (unfortunately) too common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a versioning issue. Check your .config file for binding redirects for dryioc.

It appears `DryIocNancyBootstrapper` thinks it's using version X of DryIOC, but instead it's using version Y (due to a binding redirect), which doesn't have that method (either it was removed or it's an older version that doesn't yet have it).

Figure out what version `DryIocNancyBootstrapper` wants (i.e., version X in the example above) and reference that version.

Comment: In case someone else stumbles upon this. While I have accepted this as an answer. I have had contact with the repo owner of DryIoc afterwards. He suggested to try and update the DryIoc package inside the DryIocNancyBootstrapper. I haven't had the time yet to test it

Comment: He's absolutely correct.  That's why the answer is `Figure out what version DryIocNancyBootstrapper wants (i.e., version X in the example above) and reference that version.`  Reference it in *your* project.